# How can I use Angular 1.5 service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have this service

```
class NgCartItem {
constructor($reactive,  $log) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$log = $log;
};

item (id, name, price, quantity, data) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setPrice(price);
    this.setQuantity(quantity);
    this.setData(data);
    // how to return here real object not toObject function????
    // to work properly with inCart.setQuantity(quantity, false);
    return this.toObject();

};


setId(id) {
    if (id) this._id = id;
    else {
        this.$log.error('An ID must be provided');
    }
};

getId() {
    return this._id;
};
setQuantity(quantity, relative) {
    var quantityInt = parseInt(quantity);
    if (quantityInt % 1 === 0) {
        if (relative === true) {
            this._quantity += quantityInt;
        } else {
            this._quantity = quantityInt;
        }
        if (this._quantity < 1) this._quantity = 1;

    } else {
        this._quantity = 1;
        this.$log.info('Quantity must be an integer and was defaulted to 1');
    }
};

getQuantity() {
    return this._quantity;
};

toObject() {
    return {
        id: this.getId(),
        name: this.getName(),
        price: this.getPrice(),
        quantity: this.getQuantity(),
        data: this.getData(),
        total: this.getTotal()
    }
};

}

const name = 'NgCartItem';

// create a module
export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor
]).service(name, NgCartItem);
```

And use it in this way

```
import { name as NgCartItem } from './ngCartItem';
import { name as storeService } from './store';

class NgCart {

constructor($reactive, $window, storeService, NgCartItem) {
    'ngInject';
    store = storeService;
    this.NgCartItem = NgCartItem;
}   

addItem(id, name, price, quantity, data) {

    var inCart = this.getItemById(id);

    if (typeof inCart === 'object') {
        //Update quantity of an item if it's already in the cart
        inCart.setQuantity(quantity, false);
    } else {
        // here how I created it
        var newItem = this.NgCartItem.item(id, name, price, quantity, data);
        this.$cart.items.push(newItem);
    }
};
}

const name = 'NgCart';

// create a module
export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor,
    storeService,
    NgCartItem
]).service(name, NgCart);
```

And here how I accessing in html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ngCartCart.ngCart.getCart().items track by $index">
                <td><span ng-click="ngCartCart.ngCart.removeItemById(item.getId())" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>

                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ng-class="{'disabled':item.getQuantity()==1}" ng-click="item.setQuantity(-1, true)"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    {{ item.getQuantity() | number }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-click="item.setQuantity(1, true)"></span></td>
                <td>{{ item.price | currency}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.total | currency }}</td>
 </tr>
```

### Now the problem.

I could get access to `item.name`,`item.price`,`item.total`, but couldn't to `item.getQuantity()` or `item.setQuantity(-1, true)`.
I think that because of my misuse of `toObject()` function. How to use service properly?
Here source of [1.3 version](https://github.com/snapjay/ngCart/blob/master/src/ngCart.js), I rewriting it to 1.5 in ES2015 style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a confusion between angular-services and ES6 classes. Your `NgCartItem` service is a singleton now, you have only one instance of it, but you need to create it for each item.

If you need to do so, you need to put class as the result of factory function

```
function NgCartItemFactory($log) {
    'ngInject';
    return class NgCartItem {
        constructor(id, name, price, quantity, data) {
            //create your stuff here
        }

        setQuantity(quantity, relative) {
        }
    }
}

export default angular.module(name, []).factory(name, NgCartItemFactory);
```

Then you can use it

```
// here how I created it
var newItem = new this.NgCartItem(id, name, price, quantity, data);
this.$cart.items.push(newItem);
```

Don't forget to call with `new` operator, because it is necessary for ES6-classes

Comment: it's working! awesome, thank you, i wrap it in service because i thought that in angular 2 there no factories and they use only services...still wondering how it works...